# Get value in string after 4th space SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

[image]

Related question so now I have a table Test with 3 columns id, value and term

TEST

| id | value | Item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AB CD EF GH IJ KL | 1 4 78 78 10 9 |

I will like a query to get the value in the Item column after the 4th space. In this case that will correspond to 'IJ' in the value column and in the "Item' column it will return '10'

This is what i tried

```
select 
    substring(item(REGEXP_COUNT(  SPLIT( TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(value, '[^[:digit:]]', ' ')), 'IJ')[0] , ' ')
from Test
```

Comment: Er, why not just `SPLIT(value, ' ')[4]` instead…?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `split_part()`

```
select split_part('AB CD EF GH IJ KL', ' ',5);
```

This function split the string on the chosen character and allows you to choose which one you'd like to return as a string.  In this case, the 5th part.